# Can't call firebase cloud function from my frontend

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, frontend

I've been trying for at least an hour now. The function `makeUserAdmin` is deployed to firebase. I also have other cloud functions that DO run (triggered by `auth.user().onCreate()` and `auth.user().onDelete()`.
Look at the line with the Chinese comment, isn't that how I'm supposed to reference a cloud function from the frontend? Apparently, I don't know exactly how to import that functionality, because typescript is not giving me any help/autocomplete.
Must I import something related to firebase-functions in my index.html via CDN? (btw I have other services imported via CDN like that.

```
// @ts-ignore
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// @ts-ignore
// import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

// const firebase = require("firebase");
// // Required for side-effects
// require("firebase/functions");

// @ts-ignore
const makeAdminForm: HTMLFormElement = document.querySelector('#makeAdmin')!;

makeAdminForm.addEventListener('submit', (e: Event) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    makeAdminForm.reset();                                                     //this code executes

    const email: string = makeAdminForm.makeAdminEmail.value;
    //TODO check if acc with that email address exists

    var languagesString: string = makeAdminForm.makeAdminLanguages.value;
    languagesString = languagesString.replace(/\s+/g, ' '); //replace multiple consecutive spaces by one space
    //TODO check with regex, only lowercase letters and spaces
    const languagesList: string[] = languagesString.trim().split(" ");

    const makeUserAdmin = firebase().functions.httpsCallable('makeUserAdmin'); //你看这里
    makeUserAdmin({ //context must not be passed manually
        emailToMakeAdmin: email
    }).then((result: object) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

I know the function `makeUserAdmin` doesn't get called because no new logs are created in the firebase console (however, new logs are created with the other functions)

Comment: Is your Cloud Function in any location other than the default `us-central1`?

Comment: No, that's exactly the location i chose (default), as I expect most of my apps users to be in North America (I'm based in Europe btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Firebase products that you want to use (i.e. the Cloud Functions for Firebase Client SDK in your case), as follows:

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/functions";
```

see the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) ("Using module bundlers" tab) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries).

Comment: turns out I forgot to reference my javascript file from my index.html, but thanks