# How to import Firebase SDK into React Front-end

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to call my HTTP callable functions in my front-end but cannot import firebase properly. I tried reading the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#set_up_your_client_development_environment) but am still confused.

My questions:

1. Do I need to import the firebase SDK in my front-end to gain access to my deployed firebase functions?

Front-end code:

```
import "../App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from 
     "firebase/functions";    
const functions = require("firebase/functions");

export default function Navbar() {

const getViewCount = 
    firebase.functions().httpsCallable("getViewCount");
    getViewCount().then((result) => {
console.log(result.data);
});
```

2. If so, how do I do that? (The site is already hosted on firebase). If not, what am I missing here?

Here is my Firebase functions code from the backend:

```
 exports.getViewCount = functions
 .runWith({ secrets: ["YOUTUBE_API"] })
 .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const youtube = google.youtube({
  version: "v3",
  auth: process.env.YOUTUBE_API,});
  
  const { count } = await youtube.channels.list({
  id: process.env.YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_ID,
  part: "statistics",});
   const viewCount = count.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
   return {
  count: viewCount,};
    });
```

Comment: It's `firebase/functions` not `firebase-functions`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Konrad it should be `firebase/function`.

Based on your attached [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLqHD.png) it says `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase-function'`. Because you're entering a wrong syntax.

You need to add the Firebase products that you want to use (i.e. the Cloud Functions for Firebase Client SDK), as follows:

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/functions";
```

You can check this doc [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460366/cant-call-firebase-cloud-function-from-my-frontend#:%7E:text=see%20the%20doc-,here,-(%22Using%20module%20bundlers)) ("Using module bundlers" tab) and [Firebase services for web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries).

Comment: HI @Christian I appreciate the response, I've updated my question to hopefully be clear. I am having trouble understanding what to import to allow my function call in the front-end. Do you have any advice here?

Comment: Hello @bagel_boy3, I did update my answer.

Comment: Put `import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";` at the very top. it should be listed first.

Comment: Hi @Christian I added those but I get the following error: ERROR in ./src/components/Navbar.js 46:23-41
export 'functions' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/app' (possible exports: FirebaseError, SDK_VERSION, _DEFAULT_ENTRY_NAME, _addComponent, _addOrOverwriteComponent, _apps, _clearComponents, _components, _getProvider, _registerComponent, _removeServiceInstance, deleteApp, getApp, getApps, initializeApp, onLog, registerVersion, setLogLevel).  I tried adding "compat" in the import statements which I saw as a solution moving to SDK version 9, but that didn't resolve it

Answer (score 0):

I would check your tsconfig file to see what you are targeting. If you used the create-react-app it defaults to es5 and you'll get the module not found errors

Comment: Hi @closb, appreciate the response. Could you explain further? I'm not sure I understand what targeting means here. Thanks!

Comment: Check your tsconfig.json for the following - "target":  "es5",  change it to "es6" then make sure your package.json type: "module" and it should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).